# Insert blank row into a Quickbooks purchase order using ItemAggregate

Tags: quickbooks, cdata-drivers

I'm looking to automate the generation of purchase orders (POs) in Quickbooks.

We're using the [CData ADO.NET provider for Quickbooks](http://www.cdata.com/drivers/quickbooks/ado/) (desktop), but since we're using `ItemAggregate` to add lines to POs, I'm not sure the specific adapter makes a difference.

For readability, our POs have blank rows between certain sections. I'm struggling to replicate this in `ItemAggregate`. I've tried:

1. adding `<Row/>` (QB ignores this)
2. adding `<Row><ItemDescription/></Row>` (QB ignores this)
3. as #2, but with a single space in the `ItemDescription` (QB ignores this)
4. as #2, but with a tab in the `ItemDescription` (QB ignores this)
5. as #2, but with `&nbsp;` in the `ItemDescription` (QB prints " ")
6. as #5, but change `&nbsp;` to a single space after saving the PO (causes an exception: "*There was an error when modifying a PurchaseOrder. QuickBooks error message: You have no items or one or more of your amounts is not associated with an item. Please enter an item.*")

Does anyone know of a programmatic way to get QB to add a blank line to a purchase order?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The CData ADO.NET Provider has been updated to support this functionality.

You will need to add a new hidden connection property to your connection string. Add `PreserveAggregateWhitespace=true` to your connection string. Now when you insert or update transactions, your XML elements will retain their whitespace:

```
<Row><ItemDescription> </ItemDescription></Row>
```

Your `INSERT` statement for a new SalesOrder could look like:

```
INSERT INTO 
  SalesOrders (CustomerName, ItemAggregate) 
VALUES 
  ('Doe, John','<SalesOrderLineItems><Row><ItemName>Repairs</ItemName><ItemQuantity>1</ItemQuantity></Row><Row><ItemDescription> </ItemDescription></Row><Row><ItemName>Removal</ItemName><ItemQuantity>2</ItemQuantity></Row></SalesOrderLineItems>')
```

Notice the blank space in the `ItemDescription`.

You can contact the CData Software [Support Team](http://www.cdata.com/support/submit.asmx) if you need the updated build.